# Nginx Proxy not executing as expected

Tags: javascript, apache, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I make calls to the backend server were apache is running using Javascript. I have setup an nginx proxy and route all graphite and elasticsearch requests through it to the server were apache2 is running.

Nginx does make the proxy call to the server However, it adds the location to the end of the URL.

for example: http://10.xxx.xxx.23/graphite when passed to nginx will call http://23.xxx.xxx.1:80/graphite. I don't want the /graphite in the end I want ngix to simple call http://23.xxx.xxx.1:80 ?

I have pasted my nginx.conf file below

config.js

```
datasources: {
  graphite: {
    type: 'graphite',
    url: "http://" + window.location.host + "/graphite",
  },
  elasticsearch: {
    type: 'elasticsearch',
    url: "http://" + window.location.host + "/elasticsearch",
    index: 'grafana-dash',
    grafanaDB: true,
  }
}
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;
daemon off;

error_log <%= ENV["APP_ROOT"] %>/nginx/logs/error.log;
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
  log_format cloudfoundry '$http_x_forwarded_for - $http_referer - [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent';
  access_log <%= ENV["APP_ROOT"] %>/nginx/logs/access.log cloudfoundry;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  include mime.types;
  sendfile on;
  gzip on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  keepalive_timeout 30;

  server {
    listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      root <%= ENV["APP_ROOT"] %>/public;
      index index.html index.htm Default.htm;
      <% if File.exists?(File.join(ENV["APP_ROOT"], "nginx/conf/.enable_directory_index")) %>
      autoindex on;
      <% end %>
      <% if File.exists?(auth_file = File.join(ENV["APP_ROOT"], "nginx/conf/.htpasswd")) %>
      auth_basic "Restricted";                                #For Basic Auth
      auth_basic_user_file <%= auth_file %>;  #For Basic Auth
      <% end %>
    }

    location /graphite {
      proxy_pass                 http://23.xxx.xxx.1:80;
      proxy_set_header           X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
      proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
      proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
      proxy_set_header           Host  $host;

      client_max_body_size       10m;
      client_body_buffer_size    128k;

      proxy_connect_timeout      90;
      proxy_send_timeout         90;
      proxy_read_timeout         90;

      proxy_buffer_size          4k;
      proxy_buffers              4 32k;
      proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
      proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }

    location /elasticsearch {

      proxy_pass                 http://23.xxx.xxx.1:9080;
      proxy_set_header           X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
      proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
      proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
      proxy_set_header           Host  $host;

      client_max_body_size       10m;
      client_body_buffer_size    128k;

      proxy_connect_timeout      90;
      proxy_send_timeout         90;
      proxy_read_timeout         90;

      proxy_buffer_size          4k;
      proxy_buffers              4 32k;
      proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
      proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }


  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
proxy_pass                 http://23.xxx.xxx.1:80;
```

Try this to avoid location

```
proxy_pass                 http://23.xxx.xxx.1:80/;
```